# can we specify the jenkins job to run only if the pull request is from specific branch and to a specific branch

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I have a Jenkins PR job that is created for a specific branch, but I want to modify the job to run only if the request is to merge to a specific branch or else no action needed.

Jenkins PR job A -> to run only if the PR request is from branch B_A and to merge to branch B_B.
Then only trigger this Jenkins PR job.

If the request is from branch B_A but to merge to any other branch apart from branch B_B.
Then do not run this PR job.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please specify what more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy to implement. Simply create a new job that gets triggered when a PR is created from branch `B_A`. Then, in the pipeline body, check to see if the target branch is `B_B`. If it is, trigger the PR job.

To get the target branch, you could use set the job type to multi-branch pipeline. In this case, the target branch is recorded in the variable `CHANGE_TARGET`.

Or, if you are using any of the mainstream Git hosts (BitBucket, GitHub, GitLab, etc...), they all have an API you can call to get the target branch of a specific PR.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I want to keep this as a freestyle job and not a multi-branch pipeline.